# Do all the projects that reference each other need to be in same target framework?

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-client-profile, .net-framework-version, project-reference

I have a `windows-form` application which consists of three sub projects.

```
Project A - Classes
Project B - Classes
Project C – view (win forms)
```

When I try to add reference to of ***project B*** to ***project C*** it adds the reference fine. But when I build the project is comes with the error message saying that I am missing the reference to the ***Project B***.

But later I found that ***Project C*** was set to target framework - `.net framework 4 client profile` and ***project B*** `.net framework 4.` When I changed the target framework to .net framework 4 in project c it all started work fine. 
What is the reason behind that?

Is it necessary that all projects needs to be in same target framework if they reference each other?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not reference other projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562013/can-not-reference-other-projects)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx):

"If you create a project that targets an earlier version of the .NET Framework, you cannot set a reference in that project to a project or assembly that targets the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile or .NET Framework version 4."

Comment: yes, it says **that targets an earlier version of the .NET Framework**. The problem is both project are in .net framework 4. Difference is .net framework 4 and .net framework 4 client profile.

Comment: see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx): "If you are targeting the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, you cannot reference an assembly that is not in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile" (also, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668079.aspx)