# Can't add a reference to my project - it simply doesn't detect it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

So I found this wonderful library called [WatiN](http://watin.org/) - and I've downloaded the latest version - v2.1.
I've opened a Console Applications (obviously C#) and wrote my most simplest program:

```
using WatiN.Core;
...
FireFox browser = new FireFox(@"..");
browser.Button("Send").Click();
browser.Dispose();
```

It's nothing much.
I obviously added a reference to my project by right-clicking the project > Add Reference > browsed to `C:\...\WatiN\bin\net40`, chose `WatiN.Core.dll` (like the Readme said)
The VS was auto completing my typing - and he offered me alternatives (you know - when you type con and he shows that lil' window and showing you `Console` etc) - like he should, because I've added the reference.
Then I hit compile - and suddenly - VS turns blind and he can't detect the DLL I referenced.
The DLL still shows up in the `References` folder in my project - but VS whines that it doesn't.
He says: `The type or namespace name 'WatiN' does not exist in the namespace 'WatiN' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Although he did not show those errors before compile - and marked `Firefox` in green (because its a class).
Can anyone help me with this? Maybe well me whats wrong ?
Another thing - when double clicking the DLL in the reference (aka Object Browser) it shows me it and everything's OK - but after I try to compile - it magically disappears.

Comment: Are you missing any other reference required by your external assembly?

Comment: The readme clearly states what I need - and besides, the examples only included that DLL - nothing further (and the compiler great)

Comment: Another thing - when double clicking the DLL in the reference (aka Object Browser) it shows me it and everything's OK - but after I try to compile - it magically disappears.

Comment: Tried to restart VS, or to recreate your project?

Comment: Sometimes I've gotten such errors when I had the wrong framework version target for my project, such as 4.0 Client Profile, when I needed the full framework.

Comment: you just have one external assembly copy? I mean, maybe you could to have two different versions... just ideas...

Comment: @Marlyn Morgan-Grahan Woah - Microsoft always surprise me. That fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Visual Studio 2010 suddenly can't see namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/c-visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your project settings, change your Target Framework from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4". That did the trick for me.

Comment: thanks a lot. I spent a long time trying to find out what went wrong, because my windows service project wasn't building even after adding references to class library project.

Comment: for my case, I had to edit the project (by unloading the project and editing the csproj file) to change the target framework to v4.0.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: THANK YOU!  D'oh!  A mismatched .NET framework answer in a slightly different context has given me the majority of my reputation.  They really ought to make it more obvious!!!