# Where does the project reference gone?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a project (A) that holds reference to other project (B). When I rebuild project A, I get the error:

> Error   58  The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProj' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I add (again) reference to project B, the red lines disappear and everything is fine. When I rebuild again (in order to execute the application) I get again that Error 58.

Where does the project reference gone??

Comment: Are you using source control? Is this happening after you get the latest version from the code repository?

Comment: @Naor: Have you named your B project 'Services' ?

Comment: @S.Amani: Yes. Services is project B.

Comment: @Naor: Have you any WebService in your project ? I mean in project A.

Comment: @S.Amani: No. Project A is winform project.

Comment: @Naor: Please let me know if the provided answer solved your problem.

Comment: @S.Amani: Do you have this kond of error too?

Comment: @Naor : No I haven't, why did you ask this ?

Comment: @S.Amani: Curios. I will update you about your answer.

Comment: @S.Amani: I marked the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems project's  .NET versions conflict. Something very similiar happened to me in those cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/c-visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace/4880805#4880805

Answer (score 0):

Is project B getting a compile time error?  This would be your problem.  Make sure B compiles or you can't reference it.

Comment: Are you using the full name path to Services?

Comment: Also, close VS and restart it -- sometimes VS gets wonky.

Comment: Restart VS doesn't help. I am using the "using" statement and then later in the code I use class from project B.

Comment: Yes but the error message implies it is looking in MyProj not in the second library -- use a fully qualified name to the reference and make sure they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please include the output window content after rebuild? Sometimes the output file cannot be copied and this leads to similar issues

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a conflict between your project, i recommend you to change your project B assembly name and then delete its exist assembly in project A and add it again.