# Lite version of .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net

Can I find a lite version of the .Net framework which is sufficient only for serving my application?

If I have an application which only uses few classes of .Net, I feel it is not reasonable thing to install the whole components of the entire .Net framework.

Is there any way to just install what exactly I need from the .Net framework?

Comment: What os are you on?  Recent versions of windows come with .net already, so the point may be moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but from .NET 3.5 onwards there's the ["client profile"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) which is considerably smaller than the full framework. For example, the [standalone installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24872) for the .NET 4 client profile is only 41MB.

Comment: 41MB for the 64bit version and 28.8 MB for the 32bit version.

Comment: @Steven isn't it the same version for both x86 and x64 ?! even the name says so.

Comment: The full version of .NET 4 is 48 MB.  The client profile is pretty pointless and I wouldn't recommend it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/c-sharp-visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace/4880805#4880805

Comment: Yes, sorry. 41 MB is for the client profile version that includes both 64 and 32 bit.

Answer (score 4):

Hanselman produced a nice site that explains [all the options](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/) but fundamentally you'll need the minimum client profile install.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing such as a "light version" of the .Net framework. Your best option is to use the client profile.