# .NET dll not appearing in using directive

Tags: c#, dll, reference, using, directive

For most .NET dlls, you can add them as a reference, and then "import" them into your code by means of using directive (e.g. `using mydll;`). I have a .NET binary compiled with MSVC which I can add as a reference but it never appears in the using directive. Why could this be happening?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have to add the `using` directive yourself, have you done that? Also, you're not `using` the assembly itself, you're `using` namespaces in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Visual Studio 2010 suddenly can't see namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/c-sharp-visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)

Comment: I have added the using directive myself, but I get the error 'are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?' when in fact the reference to the .dll IS there.

Comment: @david add reference by right mouse click on project>add reference>find and click OK. Try rebuild project (build>rebuild solution build>rebuild project name). Or just write your constructor from this reference, wait for wrap. Move mouse over the underline word, click it. Then press SHIFTL + ALTL + F10 (or F11 I do not remember). You will get suggestions "What do you want to do" tip. I'm working on VS2010. If you work on different find simillar shortcut for your VSXXXX

Comment: If you go into the Object Browser and limit the displayed items to just your referenced DLL, do you see the namespaces and classes you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a C++/C library, you will have to use dllimport, C# isn't going to just "see" unmanaged code.

```
[DLLImport( "mydll.dll" )];
static extern void MyMethod(int parm1, int parm2);
```

then you should be able to call MyMethod from your code as you would any other.

Comment: It is managed code though.. not unmanaged code. I already mentioned it's a .NET binary.

Comment: sorry, missed the .net binary, the comments on the question are good suggestions to start, if they don't help post the additional issues you're having when you try them.