# Switch from .NET 4 to .NET CP screws references

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an existing application that targets the .NET framework version 4.0 of which it consists some third party DLLs. When I went to switch to .NET 4.0 Client Profile,  many of my classes that I am using in these DLLs are not being recognized. I get the "Are you missing an assembly....". I want to make this switch in order to have an easier deployment experience. I tried Google, but came up short.

Any ideas why I cannot do this?

Note: the DLLs work in .NET 4 CP if I start the project targeting that framework.

Comment: Yes, it works when you start a new project.  Until you build, then all hell breaks lose.  Clearly you have a dependency on an assembly that's only available in the full version.  It is only 15% bigger, don't bother.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Visual Studio 2010 suddenly can't see namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/c-sharp-visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)

Comment: Thanks Hans... I guess they SE can close this case