# Project doesn't recognize reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csproj

Steps to recreate error:

1. Add 2 projects to a solution
2. Reference project B in project A.
3. Resolve all outlying references (maybe project B requires project C and D).
4. Build the solution successfully.
5. Attempt to use project B's namespaces in project A.
6. Fail miserably.

I've had this problem in the past when project B and project A have different target frameworks (one being .NET Framework 4 and one being .NET Framework 4 Client Profile), but that isn't the case here.

what do?

Comment: Given that this would normally work fine, it would be helpful if you'd provide real, detailed steps (with minimal but complete sample code) so that we could try to do the same thing.

Comment: Expand on 6 - what are the error messages? I have done what you have described many times without a problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately I am working on (not my own) proprietary code and cannot share it.

Comment: @Oded There are none. It simply doesn't recognize project B's namespace.

Comment: But you _can_ write an example that shows the problem and that doesn't have your proprietary code.

Comment: @Oded I may routinely start including `throw new InvalidOperationException("Fail miserably");` in my applications

Comment: @Matthew: I wasn't asking you to share proprietary code. I was asking you to share steps to reproduce the problem. Your posts starts "Steps to recreate error" but they don't really help us to recreate it... If you can't reproduce it without referring to proprietary code which we can't see, it's going to be hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: When you try using the classes in the namespace, do things compile or fail? Do you have a class in Project A that has the same name as the Namespace or start of the Namespace is Project B?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have only run into the problem with this project. If I create a blank solution and perform the above I'm sure it will work too. I was hoping for some suggestion at possibilities, not a diagnosis. For example two possibilities are: 1) Different target frameworks. 2) Build errors in project B.  Neither of those are the case here.

Comment: @Oded They both partially share the same namespace name (company prefixes) but the full namespace is not the same. I will try replacing the namespace in project A entirely and see what happens.

Comment: If that works, I'd suspect a naming conflict of some sort. Check the _class_ names.

Comment: @Matthew: You're sure, or you've tried it? Basically, you need to try to simplify things as much as possible (e.g. getting rid of other dependencies, so there's just A and B) until *either* you've worked out what's wrong *or* you've got something we can reproduce.

Comment: That had no effect. The class names are different. The namespace is different. Intellisense doesn't recognize it either in a using or by calling the namespace directly. If I ignore intellisense and try to reference the class anyways, I get build errors.

Comment: Also, project B's dll does appear in the Bin directory of project A when I compile it.

Comment: Also, I actually have several projects in this solution. I am able to use all others (let's call them projects C - G) in project A. Only project B is a problem.

Comment: @Oded The type or namespace doesn't exist.

Comment: How have you referenced project B in A?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  VS2008? VS2010? Do you have service packs installed? etc.

Comment: Right click on references -> Add reference. Project reference.

Comment: @dthorpe VS2010: 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Comment: Have you cleaned the build? Are you sure the dll for project B is the latest one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Visual Studio 2010 suddenly can't see namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/c-sharp-visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)

Comment: @Oded Yes, I always use rebuild, but have tried cleaning and then building, all to no affect. I have the latest build of project B.

Comment: @Matthew are there any external dlls that project B references that none of the other projects have? Ex: NHibernate

Comment: This is a game of 20 questions.  If there is information in the comments that can make this a real question, then please, update the question and then vote to reopen.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. That is not the issue but it could be related. My project A was originally Client Profile, but I changed it as I have run into the issue before.  However project B uses System.Web, System.Configuration, which my project A do not have.  I have tried adding them now but it still doesn't work. I am also having a secondary issue where I cannot bring up the "Add Reference Dialog" due to, supposedly having a path that's too long (the project B path). If I remove it manually in the csproj it fixes it temporarily. I'm wondering if that issue is involved here.

Comment: Thanks to Oded JonSkeet HansPassant norlando and others for contributing towards putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean a scenario, where B contains classes with member signatures refering to C and D. For example:

C:

```
public class C {
}
```

B:

```
public class B {
   public C GetC();
}
```

and A:

```
public class A {
   public void Foo() {
      B b = new B();
      b.GetC();
   }
}
```

In other words, A also uses C. Then, obviously A also uses C even if you think it doesn't.