# Visual Studio 102 Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'd been peacefully developing my software in Visual Studio 2010, but suddenly this new problem has come up.

I'm getting a huge list of errors as soon as I view the code of any dataset. Then I've to close and reopen the project. If I view the code again to modify, 102 errors fill up the error list again.

All of them are of the kind "Type 'XXX' is not defined", and they occur in .Designer.vb of various .vb files in my project.

Here is a screenshot
[image: Error list]

I've installed all the latest updates from Microsoft Update. I'm stuck and have no idea what is causing this.

Kindly help me in this regard. Thanks.

UPDATE : I've been able to pin point the cause. The following automatically generated code was causing problem.

```
Namespace Export.dsAirlinesTableAdapters
Partial Public Class AirlinesTableAdapter
' Remaining Code Here
End Class
End Namespace
```

(Export is the name of my project)

If I remove the "Export." part from the first line, everything is fine again. I'm currently at peace again, but still would like to know the cause of the problem and prevent it in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 suddenly can't see namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)

Comment: @hans-passant Nope. I tried working that out. That solution doesn't help me.

Comment: Well, it is a clear answer to your question.  The problem is that your question isn't documented well enough.  There's no point in obfuscating the real error message and not telling us why you expect that identifier to be recognized.

Comment: @hans-passant I've added a screen shot. I did not mean to obfuscate anything. Sorry.

Comment: Sounds to me like your project is missing a reference, or a namespace has a typo