# Namespace becomes unavailable on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2010 suddenly can’t see namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)

I'm adding a reference to project2 from project1.  They are in the same solution. I can access the namespace of project2 from within project1 at this point.  However, once I build the solution or project1, project2 namespace is no longer available in project1.  I've restarted VS2010 but that didn't help.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: what kind of project(s)?

Comment: I noticed that Intellisense sometimes differs from compilation. First guess would be to check the projects' .net versions.

Comment: Are the binaries for Project2 being copied to the Project1 output folder? More specifically, are the Project2 binaries available to Project1 at runtime?

Comment: project1 is console and project2 is library.  Both c#.

Comment: @RJ, I haven't done anything to modify that and not sure where I would. So I'm not sure what the answer is.

Comment: @4thSpace - right click the project reference for Project2 and look at its properties. Copy Local = True usually helps.

Comment: Probably.  Although they're dealing with a Winform app.  I'm not sure how many app configurations this happens with.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, I had to change the console app from '.NET Framework 4 Client Profile' to '.NET Framework 4'.

Answer (score 0):

And after you added the reference to 'project2', you did add a 'using project2;' statement?