# Can't use referenced DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I have added a reference to an external of my project and solution `.dll` file, I can see it under the `References` node in the Solution Explorer window, but it can't find it when I try to use it in the statement `using dllfilename`, so I basically can't use the library. 
When I go to the Object Browser - I find the Namespace of the project and it's classes/methods but I can't see the referenced library or at least its namespace or whatever...

Comment: please post the solution tree[image] in Visual Studio

Comment: Shouldn't you use the namespace rather than the filename?

Comment: What kind of dll is it? Is it a CLI assembly at all? 
Also, you need to specify the namespace instead of the dll name.

Comment: restart computer , using is namespace name not dll name.

Comment: Please post screenshot of `dll`'s available namespaces opened in *Object Browser*.

Comment: I like Nahum Litvin's advice. Restarting your computer is the solution to everything when using Windows.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans, as if the same couldn't be applied to ANY operating system ^^

Comment: There was no problem at all with the referencing or whatever. 
I just restarted the Visual Studio and I was already able to see the namespace of the `.dll` file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in VS2010. The solution is easy: Project -> Properties -> Application tab -> change Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4" instead of the Client Profile that is selected by default.

Comment: Actually this isn't a bug. The *Client Profile* is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 assemblies. If the referenced assembly is linked against the whole .NET Framework 4, it cannot be referenced from a project, linked against the *Client Profile*, since it could be that it uses some assemblies the *Client Profile* doesn't contain.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `using dllfilename`. The correct usage is `using NamespaceThatIsAccessibleFromDll;`. Once you do that, you can use the public classes that appear in this namespace.

Comment: okey, I opened the `.dll` file's code and the namespace is `dk.ms_it` but it's the same problem - it can't find the namespace, so I can't include it in the `using` statement

Comment: You may not be using the right Framework. Check NDJ's answer.

Comment: There was no problem at all with the referencing or whatever. 
I just restarted the Visual Studio and I was already able to see the namespace of the `.dll` file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try project, properties; in the application tab under target framework if you have .NET Framework 4 (Client Profile) (or 4.5 Client Profile) then change it to the appropriate version without the *client profile*.  This has caught me out a few times - and I'm not alone -

[Can't see namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880685/visual-studio-2010-suddenly-cant-see-namespace)